# is the Access token expired?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I want that everyone can send a message to a friend **after the user is logged out from facebook**.

So I save the access token but when I logout from facebook, then facebook tell me that the token is expired because the user is logged out.

Maybe do I have to request some particular **permission** ? I know that **offline_access** permission is deprecated... so what do I have to do ?

This is the error:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "Error invalidating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
```

P.s. I am using JS SDK but I think that this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to extend you access token, have a look at this :

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Facebook reference how to handle offline_permissions:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

You should be able to manage.

@Alexandre Couturon Reference :

If you get an Access Token client-side (JS SDK) you will get a short-lived token. You can exchange this token for a long-lived one with the exchange oAuth endpoint:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: but the token expire after 60 days so I don't think is a token expired issue. Maybe I need to request some other permissions ? This is the error that I get:    "error": {
      "message": "Error invalidating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }

Comment: No, if you get an Access Token client-side (JS SDK) you will get a short-lived token.
You can exchange this token for a long-lived one with the exchange oAuth endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Before I logged out, I get this: access_token=AAACZBLSe4fcoBAEmBMbHZAtTZB6uWxdnPbFrn0GU8OZByZCAzk3zNsgCZApxRBwgefkbqQQjrNYP5lpQ6ZCdG15sJ1mpIigh9G3HZBAf6z9bIQZDZD&expires=5178262 . So expires parameter ( in the previous link ) contain 60x24x60x60 seconds ( 60 days ). But when I logout from facebook, I get the error in the previous comment.